# Update autoComplete JavaFx?

Tags: binding, autocomplete, javafx-8, controlsfx

I'm currently working on a JavaFX project.I'm using Autcomplete TextField of [ControlFx](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.controlsfx/controlsfx) .Each time i add new rows in database table, it should to update Autocomplete ,i did this but my problem is showing double *Context-Menu* ,we can say double autocompletes because i call method that create autocomplete each adding of new elements in table.

**When i click a tab `editBill` i call this method :**

```java
public void showEditBill() {
    if (!BillPane.getTabs().contains(EditBillTab)) {
        BillPane.getTabs().add(EditBillTab);
    }
    SingleSelectionModel<Tab> selectionModel = BillPane.getSelectionModel();
    selectionModel.select(EditBillTab);
    /*it should remove the old autocomplete from textfield*/
    pushBills(); //Call for cheking new items
}
```

**pushBills method () :**

```java
public void pushBills() {    
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();
    bills = new BillHeaderDao().FindAll();
    for (int i = 0; i < bills.size(); i++) {
        list.add(bills.get(i).getIdClient());
    }
    //How can i remove the old bind before bind again
    autoCompletionBinding = TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(SearchBill, SuggestionProvider.create(list));
}
```

**How i can remove the old autocomplete and bind new automplete?**

[image: Description of problem]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just in any case if you need to keep instance of AutoCompletionTextFieldBinding object, thus avoiding use of:

```
autoCompleteBinding = TextFields.bindingAutoCompletion(TextField,List);
```

, which will change the instance, we could go a little bit deeper and use this:

```
// let's suppose initially we have this possible values:
Set<String> autoCompletions = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
SuggestionProvider<String> provider = SuggestionProvider.create(autoCompletions);
new AutoCompletionTextFieldBinding<>(textField, provider);

// and after some times, possible autoCompletions values has changed and now we have:
Set<String> filteredAutoCompletions = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B"));

provider.clearSuggestions();
provider.addPossibleSuggestions(filteredAutoCompletions);
```

So, through SuggestionProvider, we have "updated" auto completion values.
To avoid doubling of suggestions menu, don't use again (for the 2nd time):

```
TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(..)
```

Comment: This answer helped me to resolve many problems of AutoComplete,thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

In order to provide updates to the auto-complete suggestion list, retain a reference to the SuggestionProvider and update the suggestion provider instead:

```
TextField textField = new TextField();
SuggestionProvider suggestionProvider = SuggestionProvider.create(new ArrayList());
new AutoCompletionTextFieldBinding<>(textField, suggestionProvider);
```

When you want to update the suggestion list:

```
List<String> newSuggestions = new ArrayList();
//(add entries to list)
suggestionProvider.clearSuggestions();
suggestionProvider.addPossibleSuggestions(newSuggestions);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:
Instead of: `TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(textField, list);`
, try this:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then create binding between your textField with the list through:

```
new AutoCompletionTextFieldBinding<>(textField, SuggestionProvider.create(strings));
```

So any changes, including removing, from the list, will be reflected in the autoCompletion of the textField;
And you will have dynamic filtering of suggestions, showed in pop-up, when user enter some text in textField;

Comment: Still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some time ago I try to do as @MaxKing mentions, but it didnt work. I managed to give it a solución even though I don't think it's the right way.

// Dispose the old binding and recreate a new binding

> autoCompleteBinding.dispose();
>
> autoCompleteBinding = TextFields.bindingAutoCompletion(TextField,List);

try this:

```
public void pushBills() {
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>();
    bills = new BillHeaderDao().FindAll();

    for (int i = 0; i < bills.size(); i++) {
        list.add(bills.get(i).getIdClient());
    }
    autoCompletionBinding.dispose();
    autoCompletionBinding = TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(SearchBill, SuggestionProvider.create(list));
}
```