# JavaFX - Autocompletion TextField that suggests only matching item starting with input (SuggestionProvider not accessible)

Tags: java, javafx, autocomplete, controlsfx

I would like the Autocompletion to suggests only matching item that START with the user's input, instead of showing all the item that CONTAIN the user's input.
One way I found is to use SuggestionProvider, but I can't get it imported on my Class.

---

I'm trying to use an autocompleted TextField with controlfx ( TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(...) ), which kinda works but doesn't act as I would like.

I have a TextField where you can start typing a number of an account and the autocompleted TF suggests a list of all account which contains the user's input in his number.
For example, if I start typing "4", the suggested list shows "4710....", "4712...", ..., but also "624...", "74....". I guess the last accounts are shown because they CONTAINS my input.

It's not what I want so I found a way to make it acts like I want : by passing a list with only accounts that start with the user's input :

```java
TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(myTextField,
UIUtils.comptesListToStrings(db.getComptesStartingBy(myTextField.getText())));
```

But I need to update it whenever the input text changes.
So I found a way by using a SuggestionProvider like this ([Update autoComplete JavaFx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45778462/update-autocomplete-javafx)):

```java
Set<String> autoCompletions = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C"));
SuggestionProvider<String> provider = SuggestionProvider.create(autoCompletions);
new AutoCompletionTextFieldBinding<>(textField, provider);

// and after some times, possible autoCompletions values has changed and now we have:
Set<String> filteredAutoCompletions = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("A", "B"));

provider.clearSuggestions();
provider.addPossibleSuggestions(filteredAutoCompletions);
```

But I can't make it work when I try to import SuggestionProvider.
Eclipse suggests me "Import 'SuggestionProvider' (impl.org.controlfx.autocompletion)" but when I do, I get an error like :

```java
import org.controlsfx.control.textfield.TextFields; // <-- this works perfectly
import impl.org.controlsfx.autocompletion.SuggestionProvider; // <-- "The type impl.org.controlsfx.autocompletion.SuggestionProvider is not accessible"
```

[Import suggested by Eclipse (img)](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

[After importing (img)](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

I believe this package is in the same jar as the first line (org.controlsfx.control.textfield.TextFields --> controlfx-11-1-2.jar):
[dependencies tree (img)](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

I'm using Maven for dependencies, on Eclipse.

I tried to found a solution but couldn't make it.
So here I am, asking for help to solve this.
If there is a way to make the default `bindAutoCompletion` only showing accounts that START WITH the users's input instead of showing all accounts that CONTAIN the user's input, it would also be great.

I'm a beginner in Java and this is my first post on stackoverflow, so please excuse my low-knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `impl.*` packages are, by design, not part of the public API and not accessible.

Instead, use the version of `bindAutoCompletion` that [takes a `Callback`](https://controlsfx.github.io/javadoc/11.1.2/org.controlsfx.controls/org/controlsfx/control/textfield/TextFields.html#bindAutoCompletion(javafx.scene.control.TextField,javafx.util.Callback)).

The `Callback` is a function from a suggestion request to a collection of suggestions. It will be invoked when the text in the text field changes, and you can retrieve the text from the request using the `getUserText()` method. This way you can use arbitrary logic to map the text field text to a list of suggestions.

Here is a quick and dirty example that ensures the suggested text starts with the text in the text field:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.controlsfx.control.textfield.TextFields;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        TextField textField = new TextField();
        List<String> allItems = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 100; i++) allItems.add(String.valueOf(i));

        TextFields.bindAutoCompletion(
            textField,
            suggestionRequest -> matchingItems(allItems, suggestionRequest.getUserText())
        );
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(textField);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private List<String> matchingItems(List<String> allItems, String prefix) {
        List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String s : allItems) {
            if (s.startsWith(prefix)) {
                matches.add(s);
            }
        }
        return matches ;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```